# Php Navigation issue

Tags: php, navigation

I got this line of code right here:

```
<?php include_once('pages/component/header.php') ?>
<?php include_once('pages/component/nav.php') ?>
<!-- BODY -->
<?php 
$action=$_GET['status'];
switch($action)
{
     case 'about': include_once "pages/about.php";break;
     case 'portfolio': include_once "pages/portfolio.php";break;
     case 'contact': include_once "pages/contact.php";break;
     default : include_once "pages/default.php";break;

}
?>
<?php include_once('pages/component/footer.php') ?>
```

but when I'm surfing in to the page on WAMP localhost, I get this error saying:

Notice: Undefined index: status in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 5

Does any body know why this occurs?

It works just fine when I upload it on my FTP.

Comment: I suspect in both cases you're attempting to read a non-existent member of `$_GET`, but your WAMP system is set with a different value of `error_reporting` in php.ini. If there is no status in the query string, you can suppress errors by changing the 5th line to `$action=@$_GET['status'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not first checking if there is a `$_GET['status']` variable. For example, if you go to your URL like this: `http://localhost/index.php` OR `http://localhost/` then there is no `$_GET` variable set. With the code you have, it will always work as long as you have at least `?status=` in the url. You **must** set that variable if you are going to use it.

It is best to first *check* to see if there is a $_GET variable in the URL. This should fix your problem:

```
<?php include_once('pages/component/header.php') ?>
<?php include_once('pages/component/nav.php') ?>
<!-- BODY -->
<?php 
$action= (isset($_GET['status'])) ? ($_GET['status']) : ('');
switch($action)
{
     case 'about': include_once "pages/about.php";break;
     case 'portfolio': include_once "pages/portfolio.php";break;
     case 'contact': include_once "pages/contact.php";break;
     default : include_once "pages/default.php";break;

}
?>
<?php include_once('pages/component/footer.php') ?>
```

Comment: You have syntax error. It should be  `? ... :` instead of `: ... ?`

Comment: Tried this, but I get a syntax error. Im quite of a rookie when it comes to PHP..

Comment: I fixed the syntax error. It was missing a closing parenthesis. Try it now. (Recopy/Paste code above)

Comment: Can't thank you enough. worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: That's great! Please mark this answer as correct for everyone else who comes across a similar problem :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

It means `$_GET['status']` is not defined. This refers to the query parameters, so `index.php?status=something`

You can check for it first, like `if( isset($_GET['status'])){`

Answer (score 0):

It says that `$_GET['status']` simply doesn't exists. It's not an error it's a notice.

Difference between you local environment and remote one is in configuration. This notice still exists, but it's just not displayed.
You can configure it via `display_errors` and `error_reporting` variables in PHP.ini or alternatively configure them on runtime in PHP.

To solve it you can just check if it exists before you use it.

```
$action=isset($_GET['status'])?=$_GET['status']:'';
```

or

```
$action=empty($_GET['status'])?=$_GET['status']:'';
```

`empty()` function also checks if it exists ( `isset()` functionality) and also check if it's not empty.

Answer (score 0):

It still produces the notice on your web server, but your web server configuration doesn't allow it to be shown on the screen.

Get rid of it by using [isset()](http://php.net/isset).

```
if(isset($_GET["status"]) {
   $action = $_GET['status'];
} else {
   $action = "";
}
```